# “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) Error When Publishing Cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to publish this library https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar to cocoapods using the following command `pod trunk push Dollar.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose` and getting the following error which is preventing the publishing of the library to cocoapods. There is no build errors and all tests pass on my local and Travis CI https://travis-ci.org/ankurp/Dollar

I recently upgraded the project to use Swift 3 syntax and also updated the project to us SWIFT_VERSION=3 https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar/commit/190ba262eac738efd09408a12a433a68cc51d735 but still running into issues trying to publish.

Has anyone run into this same issue where they cannot publish a Swift cocoapods after upgrading to Swift 3 and using Xcode 8.

Comment: I'm having the [same issue](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit/issues/44). There is currently no solution I'm aware of.

Comment: This is a problem as I need to publish for people who want to use Swift 3

Comment: I'm having same issue bro, I have to publish https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager but still no solution.

Comment: There's a fix: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5864#issuecomment-247109685

Answer (score 1):

So I solved the publishing issue as such:

1. I first created a file `.swift-version` and its content set to `3.0`
2. Then I installed the following version of cocoapods before publishing `1.1.0.rc.2`

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it. At some point, we'll really have to make a assessment balance of the time lost by pod creators...